# Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

Tags: c#

I created a class called Checker. This is the code:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{ 
    public class Checker
    {
        int CheckAdminEdit(Object Temp,int counter,int allow)
        {
            int _counter = counter;
            int _allow = allow;
            Admin _Temp = Temp as Admin;

            foreach (Control c in _Temp.edit_admin.Controls)
            {
                if (c is TextBox)
                {
                    TextBox textBox = c as TextBox;
                    if (textBox.Text.Equals(string.Empty))
                    {
                        _Temp.errorProvider1.SetIconPadding(textBox, 0);
                         _Temp.errorProvider1.SetError(textBox, "Field Empty");
                        _allow++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        _Temp.errorProvider1.SetIconPadding(textBox, 666);
                        if (textBox.Name == "textBox6")
                        {
                            if( CheckEmail(textBox.Text))
                                _Temp.errorProvider2.SetIconPadding(textBox, 666);
                            else
                            {
                                _Temp.errorProvider2.SetError(textBox, "Invalid email syntax");
                                _counter++;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return (allow + counter);
        }

        private bool CheckEmail(string EmailAddress)
        {
            string strPattern = "^([0-9a-zA-Z]([-.\\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z])*@([0-9a-zA-Z][-\\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z]\\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,9})$";

            if (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(EmailAddress, strPattern))
                return true;

            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

and in my form I'm trying to declare the class with :

```
Checker try = new Checker;
```

but the first Checker in underlined also the try the = sign and the ; sign saying that Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement. Sorry if this is hard to understand, but I'm very thankful to those who can help:D

Comment: `try` is a keyword, you should use another name for the object (or something like `_try`)

Comment: HAHAHA you are right. Im so sorry for posting. ive been working on our school proiject for days now and I think I need to rest. thank you so much

Comment: @Andre: Make your comment an answer so that it can be voted on and accepted.

Comment: @user1548960 You are expected to mark the most help answer as correct.

Answer (score 4):

You haven't used parenthesis `()` for calling constructor after `new` operator. That's why you are getting `Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement` error.

Moreover try is a keyword which you cannot use as variable name.

You can do this

```
Checker @try = new Checker();
```

or

```
Checker _try = new Checker();
```

In that case you will have to access it like this

```
@try._counter = 0;
```

or

```
_try._counter = 0;
```

Comment: Be careful that the name of the variable was just the first problem. To call the constructor you have to add the parentheses, i.e. `Checker _try = new Checker();`.

Answer (score 3):

`try` is a **keyword**, you should use another name for the object (or something like `_try`)

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
Checker _try = new Checker();
```